# WinForms app - Unable to read local memory

Tags: c#, winforms, memory, 32bit-64bit

I'm retrieving the following error in a Windows Forms App (.NET Framework) by debugging execution:

[image: IndexOutOfRangeException]

And this different type of error (but in the same method) if I run the compiled exe:

[image: NullReferenceException]

Could the problem be linked to the inability to read the memory? (see the "Locals" panel on the bottom of the first picture) Why is impossible to read it?

I think the problem is memory because in the prevoius 32-bit version the application works fine, so the problem is not writing code. I'm now working at this new 64-bit version because of the 64-bit update of St7API.dll, which is called by the St7 class. I attach a few lines from this class for a better understanding.

[image: S7Lines]

Thank you in advance for any answers

**Edit:**
For other previous lines in the code there are no errors using St7API.dll. The app works fine and the error occur only when is run a specific process, maybe the the heaviest for the memory.

For the using of this API is provided a C# class (image 3) and a "closed" DLL. I add an image to the API guide for a function:

[image: API manual]

Comment: If it is related to the DLL as you think, then probably some of your p/invoke declarations are using `int` where `IntPtr` is needed, so they don't match the data size on x64.  Fixing that is going to be very specific to the details of the DLL you are calling.  As it isn't a standard OS DLL, you are going to have to describe it a lot better and provide links to the documentation (likely C or C++ documentation, as this is how most DLLs are designed to be used)

Comment: However, the error messages you are seeing (NullReferenceException and OutOfRangeIndexException) are often just bugs in your C# code, not paying attention to the length of your array.  It might be related to processing a different input / different data file and have nothing to do with x86 or x64 at all.

Comment: Thank you @BenVoigt for the answer. I'm sure that is not an array lenght issue because the code is identical to the previous version, which has no issues. Is only changed the DLL. Here a documentation of the previous version of the DLL [link](https://www.strand7.com/html/Strand7API.htm) and here for the conversion to the newest version [link](https://www.strand7.com/r3/). I add to the question images of the API guides. Do you think it could be a problem in the DLL?

Comment: But why for other previous lines in the code there are no errors? The app works fine and the error occur only in a specific process, maybe the the heaviest for the memory.

Comment: The size of Bricknodes is too small.  The size should not be fixed.  I should be based on the input parameters to the method.

Comment: Hi @jdweng, thank you for the answer. The bricknodes size is correct because the bricks (finite elements) have always the same number of nodes.

Comment: Have you already made the changes indicated in "Appendix 4 – Functions with changed parameter sizes
The table below lists R3 functions that have the same parameter list as the R24 functions, but where one or
more of the parameters have changed in size or type (typically an array length has increased in size). Careful
attention must be paid to these functions because if the size of the variable passed to the function is smaller
than what the API expects, a memory access violation or unpredictable behaviour is likely to occur." ?

Comment: In particular that note I found in their upgrade guide makes it very unsafe to assume that "that is not an array length issue because the code is identical to the previous version"

Comment: Yes, before running the code I searched for all the changes, I followed the steps in that guide. I can say that is not array lenght issue because I already made that changes and because other similar parts of the code are working. I already used the functions in the method which retrieve the error in other working part of the code (and however they are not affected by changes).